# Ubuntu didn't come on

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

After finishing the installation process and restarting the computer, Ubuntu didn't start, and no choosing option of which system I wish to use comes up. Only XP booted immediately.

What to do now?

Comment: You just need to [reinstall GRUB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_the_LiveCD_terminal).

Answer (score 0):

Try `boot-repair`, by booting into Ubuntu from Live-USB or Live-DVD.

Installing 'boot repair' with Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) by typing the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

Run/Open 'boot-repair'

```
sudo boot-repair
```

- Click on <kbd>Recommended repair</kbd> and write on a piece of paper the new [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) that will appear. Finally, reboot your PC!